# Concrete5 hardcode External Form to template

Tags: block, concrete5

I have managed to create an external form using the method: http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/external-form-email... The form worked when I embedded the block via cms. However, I need to put the form into my template. the following code did not work.

```
$b = Block::getByName('My Form');
$b->display();
```

It it probably because my external form did not have a block name. But how could I set its name?

Comment: Potentially interesting link above now missing from concrete5.org.

Answer (score 0):

Block names can only be set when the block is placed on a page (which means you're in a catch-22 here and have no way to achieve that).

Instead of attempting to output this block directly, try putting it in a global area in your template instead. You can then tell the global area to not show editing controls or the red dotted outline by disabling them. See http://concrete5tricks.com/blog/dont-hardcode-blocks-use-a-global-area-instead/

btw, you might be interested in this code I have which makes custom contact forms much easier and better than the built-in "external forms" block (in my humble opinion): https://github.com/jordanlev/c5_custom_contact_form